# What are the factors CPU utility depends on?

Tags: cpu-usage

I'm writing a java program. If run time or number of threads created by this process increase will it effect total cpu utility?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are executing a program that is doing a fixed amount of work and that work is CPU bound executing on a processor with only one core.

If your application has some parallelism that can be exploited by multi-threading, then using multiple threads intelligently will increase your CPU utilization and, so, decrease your execution time. For example, if the parallel region of your task executes in A seconds with a utilization of 10% above idle, and it can support 5 threads, then your execution time becomes A/5 seconds and your CPU utilization increases by a factor of 5 or 50%. I'm assuming a CPU bound task. For a blocking task, your execution time may decrease without impacting CPU utilization.

If your task cannot exploit parallelism, then there is some nominal increase in CPU utilization due to unnecessary threading overhead.

There are other issues that can impact CPU utilization such as what is the load on the CPU before your application executes. If it is already high, then multi-threading can cause a lot of thrashing. Additionally, if your parallel chunks are too short, then there is thread creation and destruction overhead that changes the equation.

Again, given the same task A that can be parallelized, serializing it will increase the total runtime and decrease the CPU utilization.

Note that in the above cases, the total work done is constant.